# can't show UIAlertView in iPhone although I added show

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

I wrote this code to define the `UIAlertView`

```
-(void)showAlertMethod2 {
progressAlert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"تتم المزامنة..يرجى الانتظار ...\n" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
CGRect alertFrame = progressAlert2.frame;
UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(135,alertFrame.size.height+55, alertFrame.size.width,30);
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
activityIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[progressAlert2 addSubview:activityIndicator];
[progressAlert2 show];
}

-(void)dismissAlertMethod2
{
[progressAlert2 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

And I'm Calling here:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showAlertMethod2) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

[self performSelector:@selector(syncToServer) withObject:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(syncFromServer) withObject:nil]

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(dismissAlertMethod2) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

`syncToServer` is a method to synchronize data to server and `syncFromServer` is to synchronize data to server

the problem is that the `UIAlertView` not show, anyone know what's missed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the showAlertMethod2 from main thread.

Comment: can you show me how by sample code?

Comment: Thread (different from mainThread) shouldn't be allowed to modify UI...

Comment: can you explain how to fix this. your words not enough for me.

Comment: In your code. You not set the Delegate. you Add delegate first.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by the following code

```
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self showAlertMethod2];
                });

                [self performSelector:@selector(syncToServer) withObject:nil];
                [self performSelector:@selector(syncToServer) withObject:nil];
                [self performSelector:@selector(syncToServer) withObject:nil];
                [self performSelector:@selector(syncFromServer) withObject:nil];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self dismissAlertMethod2];
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the `NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:` to `Show` the `UIAlertView` also to `dismiss` your `UIAlertView`, the thing is you now have 2 separate `NSThreads` one for showing the alert and the other to dismiss it. So you can't figure which `Thread` will finish first. so maybe the the second Thread wich dismiss the UIAlertView finishes first, which will prevent the `UIAlertView` to Show.

try to call the `UIAlertView` without creating new Thread for each method.

```
[self showAlertMethod2];
[self dismissAlertMethod2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)showAlertMethod2 {
    progressAlert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"تتم المزامنة..يرجى الانتظار ...\n" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    CGRect alertFrame = progressAlert2.frame;
    UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(135,alertFrame.size.height+55,    alertFrame.size.width,30);
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    activityIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [progressAlert2 addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [progressAlert2 show];
}

-(void)dismissAlertMethod2
{
    [progressAlert2 dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

This is your method just fine.

Now call them like

```
-(void)syncBothWay{
    [self showAlertMethod2];
    [self performSelector:@selector(syncToServer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(syncFromServer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void)syncToServer{
    //sync
}

-(void)syncFromServer{
    //sync
    after sync completed call [self dismissAlertMethod2];
}
```